# ERROR: Registering runner... failed

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Can anyone give a solution to this error?

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 
runner=5zjGjWus status=couldn't execute POST against https://ci.gitlab.com/api/v4/runners: Post https://ci.gitlab.com/api
    /v4/runners: dial tcp: lookup ci.gitlab.com on 169.254.169.254:53: no such host
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems.
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely while registering your runner, you've specified the wrong instance url. (`https://ci.gitlab.com` instead of `https://gitlab.com`)

Try registering your runner again using `https://gitlab.com` as instance url.

Comment: Thank you I will look into it